# How can I receive mail with symfony?

Tags: email, symfony-1.4

Is there a way to read mails from pop3 recipit?

I'm already using SwiftMailer to send, but nothing about receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from here
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Building-A-PHPBased-Mail-Client-part-1/

But i'd recommend just using a 3rd party web mail package instead, as it saves you the hassle of doing alot of tedious work, when the work is already done for you.

Comment: the idea was to have a unique gateway to perform some actions trought a mail gateway (converts mails on objects and execute some php actions).